# How i can keep popup login after failed login?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I just made pop up login with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_Window(id){
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'block'){

e.style.display = 'none'
}else{

e.style.display = 'block'
}
}

</script>
```

and inside this window there is login form and ID is `popUpLogin`:

```
    <div id="popUpLogin">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="exit">
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="naytaIkkuna('popUpLogin');">X</a></p>
        </div>

    <form method="POST">
        <?
        if(isset($error))
        {
              ?>
        <label class="loginLabel"><b>KÄYTTÄJÄNIMI: </b></label><input type="text" class="input" name="usernameInput" placeholder="" required></input>
        <br><br>
        <label class="loginLabel"><b>SALASANA: </b></label><input type="password" class="input" name="passInput" placeholder="" required></input>
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="loginButton" class="loginButton">KIRJAUDU</button>

        </form>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <a href="register.php" class="registerLink">REKISTERÖIDY</a>
</div>
```

It works fine, if login details are OK, but if password or username is wrong page reloads and this popup window shutdown and there is not error message in this popup login. How i can keep this window open after this button refresh page?

Comment: which one is the element that has an id `id` in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using a raw html form for your login, the proper pattern would be to have your backend set the error state. So after the page reloads, the login form would re-open and probably show a helpful message to the user like "your email/password combo wasn't found etc". I can't tell you much about how write that without knowing your backend, but probably the backend would set a JS variable in the scope of this page.

Alternately, you could turn the login into an JS form and not reload the page, which might improve your ux here (google `XMLHttpRequest` or `sending forms through javascript` if you aren't already familiar with this pattern)